# External Angle Bisector

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry

How do you prove that for any triangle three points of intersections of bisectors of its
external angles with opposite sides belong to one line.

I'm having a hard time with the collinearity part.

Comment: Do you know Menelaos' theorem? Barring that, do you know Desargues' theorem?

Comment: I am familiar with menleaus' theorem, but I am trying to figure out how to use it in this case.

Comment: Which one would lead to a cleaner solution?

Comment: If you know Desargues and what an excenter is, then Desargues. Otherwise, try to compute the ratios in Menelaos, e.g., using the sine law.